# Create rating star radio button dinamically though ajax and check them based on value

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

i'm retrieving some reviews from my db and creating dinamically a carousel item with some radio button(actually stars) and i would like to check them based on the vote retrieved from my db.

Example:
5 Stars from review 1
3 Stars from review 2

then i would like to check 5 stars in the carousel item that rappresent review 1 and only 3 in the second one.

I was able to create the code working for the review 1, but stop working for the next ones.

Here is the Ajax Call i'm actually using. I'm not able to create a JSFiddle to recreate my problem, sorry.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: location.origin + "/php/scripts/getPtReviews.php",
        data: { ptId: ptId },
        success: function (data) {
            let classe = "active";
            let title;
            let description;
            let vote;
            let reviewer;
            $.each(data, function () {
                vote = this[0][4];
                title = this[0][3];
                description = this[0][5];
                reviewer = this[1];
                $('.carousel-inner').append(
                    "<div class=\'carousel-item " + classe + "'>" +
                        "<div class=\"carousel-caption\">" +
                            "<h5>"+title+"</h5>" +
                            "<p> Recensito da: " +reviewer+ "</p>" +
                            "<div class=\"starrating risingstar d-flex justify-content-center flex-row-reverse\">" +
                                "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"star5\" name=\"rating\" value=\"5\"><label for=\"star5\" title=\"5 star\"></label>" +
                                "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"star4\" name=\"rating\" value=\"4\"><label for=\"star4\" title=\"4 star\"></label>" +
                                "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"star3\" name=\"rating\" value=\"3\"><label for=\"star3\" title=\"3 star\"></label>" +
                                "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"star2\" name=\"rating\" value=\"2\"><label for=\"star2\" title=\"2 star\"></label>" +
                                "<input type=\"radio\" id=\"star1\" name=\"rating\" value=\"1\"><label for=\"star1\" title=\"1 star\"></label>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<p>"+description+"</p>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>"
                );
                classe = "";
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('.carousel-inner').append(
                "<p class='text-center'>Attualmente non sono presenti recensioni per questo personal trainer</p>"
            );
        }
    });
```

Thanks, Davide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i was able to resolve my problem.

```
$.each(data, function () {
            vote = this[0][4];
            title = this[0][3];
            description = this[0][5];
            reviewer = this[1];
            radioButtons = [];
            for(i = 5; i > 0; i--){
                if (i == vote){
                    radioButtons.push(
                        '<input type="radio" id="star'+i+'" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" name="rating'+uniqueName+'" value='+i+'"><label for="star'+i+'" title="'+i+' star"></label>'
                    )
                }
                else{
                    radioButtons.push(
                        '<input type="radio" id="star'+i+'" name="rating" disabled="disabled" value="5"><label for="star'+i+'" title="'+i+' star"></label>'
                    )
                }
            }
            $('.carousel-inner').append(
                "<div class=\'carousel-item " + classe + "'>" +
                    "<div class=\"carousel-caption\">" +
                        "<h5>"+title+"</h5>" +
                        "<p> Recensito da: " +reviewer+ "</p>" +
                        "<div class=\"starrating risingstar d-flex justify-content-center flex-row-reverse\">" +
                            radioButtons.join("") +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<p>"+description+"</p>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>"
            );
            uniqueName++
```

Now every radio buttons group has a different name and i'm able to check the correct star on everyone